# Why is My Domain registration disabled?

Tags: mydomain

So I have just tried to register a My Domain in my org and everything on the page is disabled.

This org does not have My Domain setup, and there is no message on the page explaining why I can't register one.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is disabled?

[image: My Domain Disabled]

Comment: What kind of org is this? I believe this is only available for production orgs, not developer orgs or sandboxes.

Comment: It's a production org. My Domain is available for dev orgs (I registered one this morning) but I think you're right about sandboxes

Comment: I'd contact support, there was some messup in the summer 13 release. I know some prod orgs lost Change Sets also.

Answer (score 4):

So I was able to discover what the problem was. The user who was trying to setup the My Domain was not a System Administrator.

I don't know what system permission was required, we didn't bother investigating. We just got someone with a System Administrator profile to fill out the page and register the My Domain.